# How to migrate many custom google-chrome user-data-dir from a Windows 10 to a new Windows 11 pc without google profiles or google sync

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, data-migration

I'm on Windows 10 and am using a lot of google-chrome instances with `--user-data-dir` and have to transfer all of them to a new Windows 11 PC (settings, open tabs, saved passwords, cookies, history, ...) with a different windows user account.

Most of them are not associated with any google account, so sync is not an option. Manually copying the folders to the new pc doesn't seem to work because some things are encrypted.

Is there a (easy) way to transfer all the user data directories or their contents?

Comment: This question is about how to move chrome "instances" which are created by specifying a `--user-data-dir` on its command line and not the one default chrome instance created during installation. And it's about migrating specifically from Windows 10. I found that it might be relevant that the target is Windows 11 because my chrome installation on Win10 is in "Program Files (x86)" and the one on Win11 is in "Program Files". So i added it to the question. This doesn't seem to be covered by that 14 years old question.

Comment: I still tried all the suggested fixes including the registry keys but none helped. After applying the registry keys and starting one of the instances chrome told me that "Some settings were reset: Chrome detected that some of your settings were corrupted by another program and reset them to their original defaults. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=ui_automatic_settings_reset)".

Comment: Another difference to the dup is that the requirements are more specific because it's not allowed to use a google account to transfer the data.

Comment: You can't move the passwords without using Google sync. If it were possible to do this, the encryption would be worthless. The linked duplicate is the answer, even if it may not be precisely the Nasr that you want.

Comment: @music2myear it would be already a win if something could be moved without google sync, like settings, open tabs and history. But i didn't succeed. Are they also encrypted the same way? Or is it possible to cut out those data so that chrome doesn't complain about "corrupted data"?

Comment: @music2myear the answer you linked doesn't answer things like why open tabs are not transferred that way and its use of "profile" seems ambiguous. If i get the single source of truth approach right, it would make sense to add those information to that question and their answers but i'm not sure if that's even possible and if it's not, would this make this question here a new one or would it forever be impossible to get those additional answers?